# Protecting routes in nextjs using supabase

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I implemented route protection by creating a protection page which I wrapped in the page to be protected whenever a user is not signed in, but if the user is signed in s/he is then taken back to the login page I wonder what I am missing in my protection page. Below is what I implemented in my Protect.js:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import {useUser} from "src/contexts/useUser"
import { supabase } from 'src/db/supabase'


const Protect = ({children}) => {
  // const {user,isLoading} = useUser()
  const {auth,isauth}=supabase.auth.getSession()
  const{user,isLoading}=supabase.auth.getUser()
  const [authenticatedState, setAuthenticatedState] = useState('not-authenticated')
  const Router = useRouter()
  useEffect(()=>{
  if(!isLoading && !user){
    
    Router.replace('/auth/login')
      }
 
},[isLoading,user,Router,auth,isauth])
  return (
   <> {children}</>
  )
}

export default Protect
```

Below is my protected page:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { subDays, subHours } from 'date-fns';
import { Box, Container, Unstable_Grid2 as Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { Layout as DashboardLayout } from 'src/layouts/dashboard/layout';
import { OverviewBudget } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-budget';
import { OverviewLatestOrders } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-latest-orders';
import { OverviewLatestProducts } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-latest-products';
import { OverviewSales } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-sales';
import { OverviewTasksProgress } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-tasks-progress';
import { OverviewTotalCustomers } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-total-customers';
import { OverviewTotalProfit } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-total-profit';
import { OverviewTraffic } from 'src/sections/overview/overview-traffic';
// import {useUser} from 'src/contexts/user'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Protect from 'src/contexts/Protect';
import { supabase } from 'src/db/supabase';


const now = new Date();

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  // const user = useUser()
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const user = supabase.auth.getUser()
    if(!user){
      router.push('/auth/login')
    }
  })
 
  return(
    <Protect>
  <>
    <Box
      component="main"
      sx={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        py: 8
      }}
    >
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={3}
        >
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            sm={6}
            lg={3}
          >
            <OverviewBudget
              difference={12}
              positive
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
              value="$24k"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            sm={6}
            lg={3}
          >
            <OverviewTotalCustomers
              difference={16}
              positive={false}
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
              value="1.6k"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            sm={6}
            lg={3}
          >
            <OverviewTasksProgress
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
              value={75.5}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            sm={6}
            lg={3}
          >
            <OverviewTotalProfit
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
              value="$15k"
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            lg={8}
          >
            <OverviewSales
              chartSeries={[
                {
                  name: 'This year',
                  data: [18, 16, 5, 8, 3, 14, 14, 16, 17, 19, 18, 20]
                },
                {
                  name: 'Last year',
                  data: [12, 11, 4, 6, 2, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13]
                }
              ]}
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            md={6}
            lg={4}
          >
            <OverviewTraffic
              chartSeries={[63, 15, 22]}
              labels={['Desktop', 'Tablet', 'Phone']}
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            md={6}
            lg={4}
          >
            <OverviewLatestProducts
              products={[
                {
                  id: '5ece2c077e39da27658aa8a9',
                  image: '/assets/products/product-1.png',
                  name: 'Healthcare Erbology',
                  updatedAt: subHours(now, 6).getTime()
                },
                {
                  id: '5ece2c0d16f70bff2cf86cd8',
                  image: '/assets/products/product-2.png',
                  name: 'Makeup Lancome Rouge',
                  updatedAt: subDays(subHours(now, 8), 2).getTime()
                },
                {
                  id: 'b393ce1b09c1254c3a92c827',
                  image: '/assets/products/product-5.png',
                  name: 'Skincare Soja CO',
                  updatedAt: subDays(subHours(now, 1), 1).getTime()
                },
                {
                  id: 'a6ede15670da63f49f752c89',
                  image: '/assets/products/product-6.png',
                  name: 'Makeup Lipstick',
                  updatedAt: subDays(subHours(now, 3), 3).getTime()
                },
                {
                  id: 'bcad5524fe3a2f8f8620ceda',
                  image: '/assets/products/product-7.png',
                  name: 'Healthcare Ritual',
                  updatedAt: subDays(subHours(now, 5), 6).getTime()
                }
              ]}
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid
            xs={12}
            md={12}
            lg={8}
          >
            <OverviewLatestOrders
              orders={[
                {
                  id: 'f69f88012978187a6c12897f',
                  ref: 'DEV1049',
                  amount: 30.5,
                  customer: {
                    name: 'Ekaterina Tankova'
                  },
                  createdAt: 1555016400000,
                  status: 'pending'
                },
                {
                  id: '9eaa1c7dd4433f413c308ce2',
                  ref: 'DEV1048',
                  amount: 25.1,
                  customer: {
                    name: 'Cao Yu'
                  },
                  createdAt: 1555016400000,
                  status: 'delivered'
                },
                {
                  id: '01a5230c811bd04996ce7c13',
                  ref: 'DEV1047',
                  amount: 10.99,
                  customer: {
                    name: 'Alexa Richardson'
                  },
                  createdAt: 1554930000000,
                  status: 'refunded'
                },
               
              ]}
              sx={{ height: '100%' }}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  </>
  </Protect>
  )
  
};

Page.getLayout = (page) => (
  <DashboardLayout>
    {page}
  </DashboardLayout>
);

export default Page;
```

I tried getting user from supabase by using getUser() hook from supabase but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`.getUser()` is an async method, so you have to use `await` to get the values, and it only returns `data` and `error` object, so there is no `user` or `isLoading`.

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
```

You can call `.getUser()` inside your `useEffect` and route the user to the login page if `data` is null.

Comment: hey,  i am also working on auth with supabase, so i just need to use that line code with a useeffect to have a fully protected route. assuming I use it on every protected page.

Comment: @Techlover69 Are you just leaving a comment, or do you have a question?